# What does fractional power of number mean

Tags: integer, fractions, exponent

I have following query in my mind for many years.I know it sounds stupid and will delete if people don't like it.

I know that 2^3 means that multiply 2 three times,3^-2 means multiply (1/3) two times.What does 2^(0.22) means. multiply 2 how many times? i mean what is logic behind fractional power of integer?

Comment: Um...is it a maths question?

Comment: Yes i know but.. lets see what i get.

Comment: You should ask this on maths.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Maths, belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a^(m/n) = n√(a^m)
```

It's n-th root of a^m

```
0.22 = 22/100
m=22
n=100
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a root.

> 4 ^ 1/2 = sqrt(4)

Comment: sir then how to explain this (0.001000203334879)^(0.2002000004344)?